# Product of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous if either of them is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

We know that product of bounded uniformly continuous functions defined on R is uniformly continuous. But is the product of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous if either of them is bounded?

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $f(x) = x \sin x$.

Since $f^\prime(x) = \sin x + x \cos x$ , wich can be of order $x$, this is not uniformly continuos.

**Edit:** added a detailed proof for the last claim.

To see that the last statement is true consider $\varepsilon > 0$. Assume $f$ is uniformly continuous. Then there is $\delta > 0 $ sucht that $|f(x+h)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$ for each $h$ such that $|h| < \delta$. Now, for integer $k$,  look at $x_k=2k\pi$, so $f(x_k) =0$, while, according to Taylor's theorem,
$$f(x_k+h)-f(x_k) =f^\prime(x_k)h +\frac{1}{2} f^{\prime\prime}(c_k)h^2$$
for some $c_k \in (x_k, x_k+h)$

Now use the formula for $f^\prime$ to see that the first term on the right hand side is equal to $\pm x_k h=\pm 2\pi k h$. without loss of generality it is positive (consider only even $k$)

Calculate $f^{\prime\prime} (x) = \cos (x) + \cos(x) - x \sin(x) =2\cos(x) -x\sin(x)$
Since $\sin$ is uniformly continuous and $\sin(x_k) =0$ we may assume that $|\sin(c_k)|\le 1/2$, say. Then the second term on the rhs is estimated by (note $\cos $ is bounded by $1$)
$$|\frac{1}{2}c_k \sin(c_k)h^2 -\cos(c_k) h^2|\le \frac{1}{4}(2\pi k +2+2h) h^2$$ So
$$|f(x_k +h) -f(x_k)|>2\pi k h - \frac{\pi k}{2}h^2 -\frac{h^2+h^3}{4}=\pi kh(2-\frac{h}{2})  -\frac{h^2 + h^3}{2}$$
Clearly the last term is smaller than the first one  on the rhs and is constant if $h$ is small and fixed. If $|h|<4$ the factor of $\pi k h$ is positive. Now fix $0 < h< \delta$ and let $k\rightarrow \infty$ to see that the lhs cannot be bounded by $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Sir, I think if derivative is unbounded then it does not imply function to be not uniformly continuous because there exists uniformly continuous functions whose derivative is unbounded, e.g., square root of x.

Comment: @akansha This is correct. The example is a counterexample, nonetheless, I added a proof of this.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{|x|})$. It is a uniformly continuous and bounded function. Then take $g(x)=x$. It is a uniformly continuous function. Over $\mathbb{R}^+$, the derivative of:
$$ f(x)g(x) = x \sin\sqrt{x} $$
is unbounded, and it is easy to check that $f\cdot g$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I'm wondering: why did you introduce the root in your example?

Comment: @Thomas: it is just the first counter-example I thought, but yours is just as fine, even easier.