# If $f,g$ are uniformly continuous and $f$ is bounded and non-periodic, then $fg$ is not necessarily uniformly continuos

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

I've just begun my grad program and we were introduced to this problem in our Analysis I course: consider two uniformly continuous functions $f$ and $g$, say from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, where $f$ is bounded. I've learned that the canonical way to disprove that $fg$ is uniformly continuous is countering the claim with $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x$.

Upon naïve inspection in Desmos, other uniformly continuous bounded functions that are also periodic will also work for $f$ for the counterexample (like the triangle wave; I don't have sufficient math background to prove or disprove that *any* function like this will work, though). **Here's the catch**: can a counterxample be built using a *non-periodic*, uniformly continuous bounded function for $f$? $g$ doesn't need to be $g(x) = x$.

I thought of a very boring possiblity: from my layman understanding, you could "shrink" the graph of $\sin$ after some value $x_0$ so that it's "periodic after $x_0$". You could still make this non-periodic function be uniformly continuous and bounded and $fg$ wouldn't be uniformly continuous. I say it's boring because it still relies on periodicity as a crucial property for the counterxample. Are there any "non-boring examples" or is periodicity always required in one way or another?

Comment: You could try $f(x) = \min( \sin x, {x^2 \over 1+x^2})$.

Comment: Non-periodic bounded counterexample here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117470/42969

Comment: For other counterexamples you could use a suitable quasi-periodic functions like $f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(\sqrt{2}x)$.

Comment: Continue with g(x) = x and just change f(x) = sin(x) to h(x) by defining h via h(x) = 0 for -π <= x ≤ π and h(x) = sin(x) for |x| ≥ π. Then h is non-periodic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x-\lfloor x\rfloor&\text{ if }\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is a perfect square and }x-\lfloor x\rfloor\leqslant\frac12\\1-x+\lfloor x\rfloor&\text{ if }\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is a perfect square and }x-\lfloor x\rfloor>\frac12\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$(see its graph below) and $g(x)=x$.

[image]